# Java get non uniform random numbers

Tags: java, random, average

I need to generate random data for a geocaching game.
I've a list of QuestMeasurement with QuestId, StageId and measurement value.

How can I generate random numbers that should have a different average per quest. (Right now all the averages are around the median of the boundries.)

Here's the code:

```
 public static int getValueForMeasurementType(String measurementType) {
        Random random = new Random();
        return switch (measurementType) {
            case HARTSLAG -> (int) (random.nextDouble() * (125 - 60 + 1) + 60) ;
            case ZWEETNIVEAU -> (int) (random.nextDouble() * 101);
            case GELUID -> (int) (random.nextDouble() * (100 - 30 + 1) + 30);
            default -> 0;
        };
    }
```

When I calculate the average per QuestId:

```
Average HARTSLAG for quest 06541BCC50F2451EA5088464E6A6CD9C: 89.41176470588235
Average HARTSLAG for quest 08BC162BBC5A456A8BE9E24E76EEBF79: 95.11764705882354
Average HARTSLAG for quest 082DC01CC9D74CF0AEA7C79EAF616EEE: 89.79411764705883
Average HARTSLAG for quest 096AE1335FD648018A95968AFC8FBB12: 91.3529411764706
Average HARTSLAG for quest 0A5C24368F084608B0506ABB61138218: 92.38235294117646
Average HARTSLAG for quest 0A2934DD6996453E84826F7A703BCBC1: 90.13725490196079
Average HARTSLAG for quest 0870A3CAD0754C3DAFA686D202024A36: 90.02941176470588
Average HARTSLAG for quest 05555A33124D4298820C6E40DDF94B4D: 88.8970588235294
```

As you can see they all seem to be around the average.

Is there a way to manipulate the randomness so that per quest it should generate random numbers in a random range within the provided range?

Comment: Linear transformations of the uniform distribution are also uniform, so the transformed mean and median will be equal to each other since that is a property of uniformity. If you want them to be different the solution is to use non-linear transformations, but there are literally an infinite number of possibillities — viewers of your question can’t really help you unless you provide more specifics about what you want.

Comment: @pjs let's start by manipulating the average with another random number (but hsould stay in the range (eg: 60 -125). Is that possible?

Comment: Why do you think you need another random number? And yes, that’s possible but *you* need to explain in greater detail what you want. As I said before, there are literally an infinite number of possible answers, your job is to narrow that down a bit.

Comment: If you disagree with the closure and the reason given, you need to edit your question and make the case that the linked answer doesn’t address what you’re seeking. Explain (with explicit details) why what you  want is different.